# Invoking native code with hand-written assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

I'm trying to call a native function from a managed assembly. I've done this on pre-compiled libraries and everything has went well. At this moment I'm building my own library, and I can't get this work.

The native DLL source is the following:

```
#define DERM_SIMD_EXPORT        __declspec(dllexport)

#define DERM_SIMD_API           __cdecl

extern "C" {

    DERM_SIMD_EXPORT void DERM_SIMD_API Matrix4x4_Multiply_SSE(float *result, float *left, float *right);

}

void DERM_SIMD_API Matrix4x4_Multiply_SSE(float *result, float *left, float *right) {
    __asm {
       ....
    }
}
```

Hereafter we have the managed code which loads the library and create a delegate from a function pointer.

```
public unsafe class Simd
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void MatrixMultiplyDelegate(float* result, float* left, float* right);

    public static MatrixMultiplyDelegate MatrixMultiply;

    public static void LoadSimdExtensions()
    {
        string assemblyPath = "Derm.Simd.dll";

        IntPtr address = GetProcAddress.GetAddress(assemblyPath, "Matrix4x4_Multiply_SSE");

        if (address != IntPtr.Zero) {
            MatrixMultiply = (MatrixMultiplyDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(address, typeof(MatrixMultiplyDelegate));
        }
    }
}
```

Using the sources above the code runs without errors (the function pointer is obtained, and the delegate is actually created.

The problem raises when I call the delegate: it is executed (and I can debug it also!), but at function exit the managed application raises a *System.ExecutionEngineException* (when it doesn't exit without exceptions).

The actual problem is the function implementation: it contains a *asm* block with SSE instructions; if I remove the *asm* block, the code works perfectly.

I suspect I am missing some registry save/restore assembly, but I'm completly ignorant on this side.

The strange thing is that if I change the calling convention to __stdcall, the debug version "seems" to work, while the release version behave as if __cdecl calling convetion was used.

*(And just because here we are, can you clarify if the calling convetion matters?)*

---

Ok, thank to the *David Heffernan* comment I find out that the bad instructions causing the problem are the following:

```
 movups result[ 0], xmm4;
 movups result[16], xmm5;
```

*movups* instructions moves 16 bytes into (unaligned) memory.

The function is called by the following code:

```
 unsafe {
    float* prodFix = (float*)prod.MatrixBuffer.AlignedBuffer.ToPointer();
    float* m1Fix = (float*)m2.MatrixBuffer.AlignedBuffer.ToPointer();
    float* m2Fix = (float*)m1.MatrixBuffer.AlignedBuffer.ToPointer();

    if (Simd.Simd.MatrixMultiply == null) {
                    // ... unsafe C# code
    } else {
        Simd.Simd.MatrixMultiply(prodFix, m1Fix, m2Fix);
    }
}
```

Where *MatrixBuffer* is a class of mine; its member *AlignedBuffer* is allocated in the following way:

```
// Allocate unmanaged buffer
mUnmanagedBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(new IntPtr((long)(size + alignment - 1)));

// Align buffer pointer
long misalignment = mUnmanagedBuffer.ToInt64() % alignment;
if (misalignment != 0)
    mAlignedBuffer = new IntPtr(mUnmanagedBuffer.ToInt64() + misalignment);
else
    mAlignedBuffer = mUnmanagedBuffer;
```

Maybe the error is caused by *Marshal.AllocHGlobal* or *IntPtr* black magic?

---

This is the minimal source to spot the error:

```
void Matrix4x4_Multiply_SSE(float *result, float *left, float *right)
{
    __asm {
        movups xmm0,    right[ 0];

        movups result, xmm0;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float r0[16];
    float m1[16], m2[16];

    m1[ 0] = 1.0f; m1[ 4] = 0.0f; m1[ 8] = 0.0f; m1[12] = 0.0f;
    m1[ 1] = 0.0f; m1[ 5] = 1.0f; m1[ 9] = 0.0f; m1[13] = 0.0f;
    m1[ 2] = 0.0f; m1[ 6] = 0.0f; m1[10] = 1.0f; m1[14] = 0.0f;
    m1[ 3] = 0.0f; m1[ 7] = 0.0f; m1[11] = 0.0f; m1[15] = 1.0f;

    m2[ 0] = 1.0f; m2[ 4] = 0.0f; m2[ 8] = 0.0f; m2[12] = 0.0f;
    m2[ 1] = 0.0f; m2[ 5] = 1.0f; m2[ 9] = 0.0f; m2[13] = 0.0f;
    m2[ 2] = 0.0f; m2[ 6] = 0.0f; m2[10] = 1.0f; m2[14] = 0.0f;
    m2[ 3] = 0.0f; m2[ 7] = 0.0f; m2[11] = 0.0f; m2[15] = 1.0f;

    r0[ 0] = 0.0f; r0[ 4] = 0.0f; r0[ 8] = 0.0f; r0[12] = 0.0f;
    r0[ 1] = 0.0f; r0[ 5] = 0.0f; r0[ 9] = 0.0f; r0[13] = 0.0f;
    r0[ 2] = 0.0f; r0[ 6] = 0.0f; r0[10] = 0.0f; r0[14] = 0.0f;
    r0[ 3] = 0.0f; r0[ 7] = 0.0f; r0[11] = 0.0f; r0[15] = 0.0f;

    Matrix4x4_Multiply_SSE(r0, m1, m2);
    Matrix4x4_Multiply_SSE(r0, m1, m2);

    return (0);
}
```

Pratically after the second *movups*, the stack changes the *result* value (stored on the stack), and stores the values of *xmm0* on the modified (and wrong) address stored in *result*.

After having stepped out from *Matrix4x4_Multiply_SSE*, the original memory isn't modified.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: You didn't show the asm code which is odd since that's where you think the problem is. I'd recommend that you do your testing from native code and keep the confusion of managed code out of the equation.

Comment: *@David Heffernan* Gulp, you are completly right: it is not the presence of __asm block, but the ASM instruction theirself to cause the problem. Now I'm trying to isolate the bad instruction, even if I'm moving only floats on *xmm* registers.

Comment: Debug works, Release crashes. This sounds like a corrupt stack. Are you missing push/pops?. Does the SP change when you execute the faulting operations?. Is the write location the correct one or are you overwriting your stack? Check in the memory window with the value of SP what is changing your stack data.

Comment: @AloisKraus Actually now also Debug crashes (I think because a temporary code smell around there). However, I think you got the point: after the first movups instruction, debugger evaluate all function parameters (pointers) to 0x00 (pointed memory by *result* is not modified). After that, the second instruction cause the system exception. How do I test the stack trace memory? The ESP register doesn't change.

Comment: The stack layout is very well explained here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames at the beginning of the function store ebp and open the address in a memory window. When you step furhter in the function you can see your stack (remember new variables are stored in smaller addresses) allocating its local variables and changing them. At the beginning ebp is put onto the stack. If this value is overwritten or something changes in a higher address as this value occurs you have a stack corruption.

Comment: Indeed I have stack corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assembly was flawed. There is a difference between

```
void DoSomething(int *x)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov x[0], 10   // wrong
            mov [x], 10    // also wrong
        mov esi,x      // first get address
        mov [esi],500  // then assign - correct
    }
}
```

The first two examples did not write to the memory location pointed to the pointer but to the storage location of the pointer itself. Since the parameter comes from the stack you did overwrite with the movups instruction your stack. You can see this in the debugger window when you call e.g.

```
int x=0;
DoSomething(&x);
```

With mov [x],10 you do not set x to 10 but you write into your stack.

Answer (score 2):

The alignment correction is wrong. You need to add `alignment-misalignment` to correct the alignment. So the code should read:

```
mAlignedBuffer = 
    new IntPtr(mUnmanagedBuffer.ToInt64() + alignment - misalignment);
```

However, I would recommend that you test the function in a native setting first. Once you know it works there you can move to the managed setting and know that any problems are due to the managed code.

Comment: +1 sounds reasonable. Although the used assembly instruction (moveUps) was the unaligned version which should not cause a General Protection exception.

Comment: @Alois I know this doesn't explain everything, but we haven't got all the info so this is at least a start.

Comment: This hasn't solved the underlying problem, but surely you saved me from another headache!

Comment: The code "crashes" in the same way also in a native application. *crashes* word is quoted because the code doesn't work, but the application doesn't terminate with an exception... this smell too much for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

I find out a solution. Loading pointer value on CPU register, and using the register for redirect to memory:

```
mov esi, result;
movups [esi][ 0], xmm0;
```

Using those instructions makes the code working as expected.

---

But the question remain unsolved completely, since the *movups* instruction can take as first argument a memory address; so if someone knows what's going on, I'm pleased to check the best answer.